# Should you check if an input is empty before using setState to clear it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Assume `input` has `value={this.state.searchValue}`.

```
  onClose = () => {
    this.setState({searchValue: ''}, () => {
      this.search();
    });
  }
```

Is this a waste if for example, the container is closed while the string is already empty?

Should checks like this be done?

```
onClose = () => {
  if (!isEmpty(this.state.searchValue)) {
    this.setState({searchValue: ''}, () => {
      this.search();
    });
  }
}
```

What if this were `Redux` state?

```
onClose = () => {
  if (this.props.inputValue) {
    this.props.clearInput();
  }
}
```

I think `Redux` is a little smarter and does a `shouldComponentUpdate` for you, so it would realize the `this.props.inputValue === ''` and `nextProps.inputValue === ''` and save a render?

Answer (score 1):

React will render the component whenever `setState()` is called. If you want to prevent this behaviour, your component could extend `React.PureComponent` and it will compare the previous state value in order to decide to render or not.

When you wrap a component with `Redux.connect`, by default it also applies a shallow comparison in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Would just checking `!isEmpty(this.state.searchValue)` work too/should I do these checks?